# What is this fungus?

Tags: plant-identification, mushrooms

What is this mushroom that appeared overnight? This is in Arkansas. Is it edible?

[image: sample pic]
[image: pic2]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As always, do not take fungal identification from random people on the internet as gospel, especially for potentially edible species. Get an expert to check. Even small amounts of poisonous mushrooms can be fatal.

For proper identification you would need to take a spore print from the underside of the mushroom/toadstool. For even a provisional identification we would need to see the gills/pore structure on the underside in full.

To give you some idea of the difficulty:

I disagree with @blacksmith37. These are almost certainly **not** chanterelles. [Chanterelles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chanterelle) are almost all funnel shaped and grow as individuals or in small groups, not overlapped strongly as these are.

There seem to be a few possible genera in the area: *[Galerina](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galerina)* species, or perhaps *[Omphalotus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omphalotus_illudens)*, both of which are quite poisonous, have similar coloration and gills on the underside and grow in clusters. Both of these species (and chanterelles too) grow on rotting wood, indicating that you possibly have the remains of a tree under your soil there. It could also be an *[Armillaria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armillaria)* species, which are gilled, but usually grow on living wood, rather than dead. If you can dig below the fungi and see whether they are growing on wood or not, that will help ID.

I think another good option is also the fairy ring mushroom (*[Marasmius oreades](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marasmius_oreades)*), which is strongly gilled, has a brownish cap, and grows in clusters on lawns.

There is a fairly good guide to some common species (for Kansas) [here](https://gpnc.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/GPNC-Mushrooms.FINAL_.pdf) (PDF). Kansas isn't too far away from Arkansas, so I would expect to find most of these species in Arkansas. It has some good ID pointers at the start.

Comment: "...do not take fungal identification from random people on the internet as gospel." Literally words to live by. In general, don't eat random things the internet says you should try.

Comment: @DonBranson what? not even tide pods??? /s